# Fixed points of the Atkin operator on $p$-adic modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

The Atkin operator $U$ on $p$-adic modular forms is defined by
$$U\left(\sum a_n q^n\right) = \sum a_{np} q^n.$$
Is there a characterization of those $p$-adic modular forms that lie in $\ker(U-1)$, i.e., those $p$-adic modular forms that are fixed by the Atkin operator? (For a fixed weight, one can construct examples using Eisenstein series.)

Comment: Since no motivation is given, what does "characterization" mean (in a manner that wouldn't be a tautology)?  Can you give an example of some analogy to this for which there is an answer that you would consider useful?

Comment: @nfdc23 This arose when I was trying to understand some computations in homotopy theory. It'd be cool to have an explicit description of the generators and relations defining ker(U-1) as a Z_p-module.

Comment: Explicit in terms of what?  Some special constructions with $q$-series? That seems implausible to expect (even after clarifying what integrality notion you are using to limit yourself to working at the level of a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module rather than with $\mathbf{Q}_p$-vector spaces or $\mathbf{Q}_p$-Banach spaces).  Just as an aside, the "definition" you mention for $U$ is better viewed as a formula and not a definition (just as with usual Hecke operators); e.g., proofs of non-trivial features of the operator rest on a more conceptual definition.